# How to work with 'NA' in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I am merging two data frames in pandas. When joining fields contain 'NA', pandas automatically exclude those records. How can I keep the records having the value 'NA'?

Comment: [Working with missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html)

Comment: I test it and for me it works. can you add some sample data? What is your pandas version?

Comment: Without raw data, code, your attempts, and errors for others to try and reproduce, this is just a speculative question

Comment: @ MaxU: For my case 'NA' is not missing data, it's valid data but pandas is excluding it by default. That's creating problem for me

Answer (score 1):

For me it works nice:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,2,1],
                   'B':[5,7,8]})

print (df1)
     A  B
0  NaN  5
1  2.0  7
2  1.0  8

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,2,3],
                   'C':[4,5,6]})

print (df2)
     A  C
0  NaN  4
1  2.0  5
2  3.0  6

print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A']))
     A  B  C
0  NaN  5  4
1  2.0  7  5

print (pd.__version__)
0.19.2
```

EDIT:

It seems there is another problem - your `NA` values are converted to `NaN`.

You can use [`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), there is possible define which values are converted to `NaN` with parameter `keep_default_na` and `na_values`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',keep_default_na=False,na_values=['NaN'])
print (df)
      a   b
0   NaN  NA
1  20.0  40
```

Comment: My data contains 'NA' which is being imported from a excel file. In your example you are using NaN. Can you check with 'NA'?